# Posting, Login in and redirecting for user

Tags: php, http, cookies, post, pear

**Here is the scenario:** when the user is clicking on a link on my webpage i want to perform a login to another site, and use the cookies to login the user to the second site.

I'm using `PEAR Request2` and i'm able to get the login cookies but when i use:

```
setcookie($cookies['1']['name'], $cookies['1']['value'], time()+3600, '/');

header("Location: http://www.example.com");
```

the cookie host is my site and i suspect that is why i get a login error.

Is there anyway to issue a cookie as the secondary site - or do you have any suggestion how can i simulate login (i have all the relevant information) and redirect the user to home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! you can only set the cookie on the client side for your domain.

I was fetching the cookies from a 3rd party website and tried to set those cookies, this can only b done using javascript :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setcookie like normal, but with just adding the domain of the cookie.

```
setcookie('cookiename','value',time()+3600,'/','.example.com');
```

However this is not suggested at all because it can open security risks.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Ill try it and post back the result!!  Thanks.

Comment: for some reason when using setcookie with the domain for the site i'm trying to login it doesnt set the cookie at all (i'm using cookie manager to track the cookies....

Comment: Try instead removing the http and www tag like above.

Comment: tried it...no luck perhaps it's not possible to set cookies on behalf of another domain?

Comment: It is but it is very insecure, and would allow anyone to create a XSS attack on your server. Try using the .example.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your script can pass some key to other site in private channel. after that you redirect to:

> http://your.other.site.com/login.php?auth_key=$auth_key

And other site can auth_user. But be carefull, you need every time generate random key and make sure that user can use this key only one time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  unfortunately this is not possible since I have many sites I would like to login and also its not my site...but thanks!!!